# Json Object with one attribute or primitive Json Data type?

Tags: json, rest

I am building a REST API which creates a resource. The resource has only one attribute which is a rather long and unique string. I am planning to send this data to the API as JSON. I see two choices for modeling the data as JSON

1. A primitive JSON String data type
2. A JSON object with one String attribute.

Both the options work.

Which of these two options is preferred for this context? And why?

Answer (score 2):

### Basic Answer for Returning

I would personally use option 2, which is: `A JSON object with one String attribute.'

Also, in terms of design: I prefer to return an object, that has a key/value. The key is also a name that provides context as to what has been returned.

Returning just a string, basically a "" or {""} lacks that context ( the name of the returned variable.

### Debate: Are primitive Strings Json Objects?

There seems to be also some confusion as to if a String by itself is a valid JSON document.

This confusion and debate, are quite evident in the following posts where various technical specs are mentioned: [Is a primitive type considered JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732737/is-a-primitive-type-considered-json/)

**The only thing for sure is that a JSON object with a key-value pair is definitely valid!**

As to a string by itself.. I'm not sure ( requires more reading).

### Update: Answer In terms of creating/updating an entity (Post/Put)

In the specific case above, relating to such a large string that "runs into a few kilobytes"... my feeling is that this would be included within the request body.

In the specific context of sending data, I would actually be comfortable with using either 1 or 2. Additionally, 1 seems more optimized ( if your frameworks support it), since the context about what the data is, is related to the rest API method.

**However, if in the future you need to add one more parameter, you will have to use a JSON entity with more than one key.**

Comment: The JSON standard only allows arrays and objects to be at the top level. Great answer!

Comment: @Evert  Thanks for clearing that up! I'm reading the discussion in that stackoverflow post and it's a bit of a mix ahhaha :D

Comment: I'm actually taking it back. I wanted to be sure, but it turns out that the RFC does indeed allow everything at the top-level: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-2

Comment: @Evert It's so annoying that they seem to have sort of changed their minds on that.

Comment: Yea! I just looked it up and it wasn't the case with RFC4627!

Comment: @Evert , reminds me of another question I had answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459954/understanding-the-additionalproperties-keyword-in-json-schema-draft-version-4/17339316#17339316 . They love driving us crazy!!!!

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos. Just wanted to clarify... I was referring to JSON data that is sent as input to the API. In this case the resource itself, I thought, will set the context as to what the data is about. For instance if the resource where to be an email (i.e. the API end point is /email) and the data is <email-id>. PUT /email/<email-id> would make sense. But as I said since the data in my case is a string running into a few kilobytes I can't model it so. So, I was looking at alternative options